# Простая таблица в C++

Tags: c++builder, qt, c++

Здравствуйте, господа!
Возникла потребность вывести в две колонки пары значений чисел. Подскажите какой-нибудь пример, желательно с комментариями(не работал с GUI), желательно в Qt, Wx или Barland C++, заранее большое спасибо.
BuilderC, конечно это все очень хорошо но дайте пожалуйста код вашей программы, я полный нуль в этом деле, книги читать некогда, сессия на носу, поэтому хотелось бы иметь законченный код и от него уже плясать по своей теме.

Answer (score 3):

В С++ Builder для этой цели имеются компоненты StringGrid, ListBox и Memo. 
Например, в цикле по i:

```
Memo1->Lines->Append(FloatToStrF(value[i], ffFixed, 4, 1) + 
  "\t" + FloatToStrF(value[i+1], ffFixed, 4, 1));
i += 2;
```

Будет выведено в Memo1:

```
.....  .....
333.3  444.4
.....  .....
```